# Haxe/Kha sound problems in Firefox/Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, firefox, audio, haxe, kha

I'm developing a game in Haxe and Kha, and I've encountered a sound related problem.

In Firefox, the sound is delayed by about 200ms. For example, when I click a button, it animates, but the `click` sound plays up 200ms later. Same goes for every other sound, and it's constantly like that.

In Internet Explorer, the sound is completely bonkers: sometimes it plays 2 sounds at the same time, and sometimes it doesn't play at all when another sound is playing.

Other browsers like Opera, Chrome, Vivaldi, and Brave all work perfectly fine and just as intended.

Does anyone out there have a solution?

Maybe it's something that is Javascript related (I'm building my game against the Javascript target).

Comment: do you have a working sample which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Unfortunately no, but i've contacted Robert which already responded me what the problem might be:

IE: Webaudi is not supported so i'm getting the error because of this
Firefox itself has been known to have sound issues and i'm further investigating it

Comment: I've tested Seamonkey, which is Firefox based, and in Seamonkey it works without any issue